# Change printer properties from command line

Tags: windows, powershell, printer

Please help, how can I change printer properties - font selection - code page from command line. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible to change printer settings from the command line.

However, what is possible is to change the default printer from the command line. You can set up multiple copies of the same printer driver, with different settings. Then you can select the setting you want with the command

```
RUNDLL32.EXE PRINTUI.DLL,PrintUIEntry /y /n "printer"
```

In this command, change "printer" to the name of the printer you want (keep the quotes).

[Rob Van der Woude](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php) has a great webpage with more information on command line printer control

Comment: but i add printer from command line as "Generic / Text Only" and I was hope that it's possibly set code page...

Comment: As far as I know that is not possible. As per my comment on your other question, please give more information on what you are trying to do. There's a lot of missing information that may help.

Comment: It's need to change code page to cyrillic for local printer whith "Generic / Text Only" driver