# Changing Advanced Printer Preferences using Command Line

Tags: command-line, printer

I was looking for a way to change The Graphic Mode settings of an HP Printer using a command. This setting is located as the below screenshot:

[image].

Comment: What commands have you tried? Where are you stuck? What else have you tried?

Comment: Also, https://superuser.com/questions/1684408/change-printer-properties-from-command-line

Comment: I would not have put up this question if it was already answered.

Comment: I didn't say it was answered, which is why I didn't tag it as a duplicate. I simply linked a related question.

Comment: What operating system? Which printer driver?

Comment: Windows 10 and HP LaserJet 4200 PCL 5e (in the screenshot)

Comment: My reply from the question @spikey_richie referenced still stands: you can't change printer settings from a command line. However, you can create a copy of the driver, with the required settings, and then select the correct driver from the command line.